# Viewing distance in Google Fit

Tags: google-fit

I can't figure out how to view distances in Google Fit. When I walk, it only shows steps and duration. Is it possible to see the distance? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At current there is no way to view distance, however it will probably come in a future update.

However you could calculate it by multiplying your steps by your average stride.

You can get your average stride by walking 10 metres, counting how many steps you take, and divide 10 by the number of steps.

One thing to bear in mind about google fit, is that it isn't designed to track say, where you went on a run, it is designed to do low power, background tracking and this is probably why there was no distance feature to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

Good news! As of [May 13, 2015](http://officialandroid.blogspot.sg/2015/05/google-fit-make-every-step-count.html), Google Fit was updated to show more kind of data: calories burned and **distance**. Note that the distance *is approximated*.

On the main screen, select the right drop-down list to change from active time/steps to distance, **or** tap/slide the big circle diagram to the second point.

You can also set the units to kilometers/miles in the settings.

[image: google fit showing distance]
<sup>(Image courtesy of Google)</sup>

Comment: Tip: I could only change from US units to normal units on my phone, not on the website. The good news is that you can switch it to kilojoules, too.

Answer (score 0):

The km is not calculated correctly in Google Fit.

It should calculate 1400 steps = 1 km

When there us a break it does not take the previous stros into account.

The calculation should be in a day how many steps walked and it should calculate 1 KM at 1400 steps.

By the process we come to know from 12 am to 12 pm how much we walked in a day in e
Steps
KM
Calories
Heart beat